# How can I log which sites an iPhone app uses?

Tags: iphone, proxy, logging, tracking

Is there a Proxy server app for mac that allows me to setup a local proxy server so I can log/track which sites an iPhone app visits?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Configure your Mac as an access point and sniff the traffic with TCPDump. Here are the steps:

- In the Wi-Fi icon of your toolbar, click `Create Network`. Give it a random name, select security, and set a password.
- In `System Preferences > Sharing` set `To computers using: Wi-Fi`. In `Wi-Fi Options...` choose the network you created before. In `Share your connection from:`, choose the interface you are getting Internet from.
- Enable `Internet Sharing`, and connect to this new Wi-Fi network from your iPhone.
- Disconnect 3G on your iPhone from `Settings > General > Network` and check your Internet with Safari. Sometimes it takes a few seconds.
- In your Mac type `sudo tcpdump -s 0 -A -i en1 port 443 > log.txt`. Use `ifconfig` if you have a network interface other than en1. The log generated can be imported by [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) (which is basically a GUI version of tcpdump), and looks like this:

  [image]
- Now all Internet traffic from your iPhone will be recorded.

TCPDump is included with all versions of OS X. For other options, see [Technical Q&A QA1176 Getting a Packet Trace](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1176/_index.html).